# Plesk Git AWS - script bash and aws commands doesn't works

Tags: bash, git, amazon-s3, plesk

in plesk I've an hosting on Git with   "Additional deployment Actions" enabled.
I created a bash script and successfully enabled the SSH access type of the hosting on "/usr/bin/bash" and everything works.

If I insert any AWS command into the sh script this is completely ignored !
I have correctly configured the aws credentials with
aws configure

if instead I launch the script from SSH shell with the same hosting user it works.

This is the sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH 
aws s3 cp ./foo.txt s3://my-foo-bar-xxx-yyy-zzz/tmp  --region eu-south-2
```

what's the problem ?

thos is my echo $PATH

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```